# How to install parted on CentOS?

Tags: centos, parted

```
root@host [/]# parted
-bash: parted: command not found
```

I am using CentOS. Looks like I simply have to yum it first or something. How would I do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a internet connected to you server, it is very easy:

```
# yum -y install parted
```

Answer (score 1):

when you get this kind of message you can easily find out what packages provides the command using yum:

```
yum whatprovides "file"
yum install "package"
```

when you run the install and it complains already installed package you can also perform:

```
rpm -ql "package" |grep file$
repoquery -l "package" |grep file$
```

To know what is the path were it is installed. We can always assume that PATH might not include the file.
I'm adding the $ at the end of the grep so that it finds everything that ends as file otherwise you will get fileabc instead of file.